# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cord' referenced before assignment

Tags: python, python-3.x

Кусок кода должен перемещать место следующего ввода значений из ed1,2,3 на 1 ячейку вниз, сделал на счетчике координата, после каждого вызова функции `cord` должен увеличиваться на +1. Изначально ему вне функции задано `1`, но при вызове функции выдает `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'cord' referenced before assignment`, якобы переменная вызвана до ее объявления.

```
cord = 1
def add_click():
    ws.write(cord, 0, ed1.get())
    ws.write(cord, 1, ed2.get())
    ws.write(cord, 2, ed3.get())
    wb.save("graph.xls")
    print(ed1.get(), "added to sheet") 
    cord += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

Использование глобальных переменных не всегда является хорошей практикой. Как вариант можно сделать функцию с возвращаемым значением:

```
cord = 1
def add_click(cord):
    # какие-то действия
    cord += 1
    return cord
```

Тогда в основной программе вызов функции `add_click` будет выглядеть следующим образом:

```
cord = add_click(cord)
```

Answer (score 0):

Проблема решена. Требовалось объявить `global cord` внутри функции